# Como adicionar fonte a um select?

Tags: css, css3

Possuo o seguinte link:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800">
```

E gostaria de adicionar ela a um select.

Já tentei colocar no CSS `select { font-family: Arial}` e não funciona.

Alguém saberia dizer como colocar essa fonte?
Abaixo o codigo que estou usando pra criar  o select

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2>
        <select name="lead_source" style="color:gray; width:100%; height:50px;" required="required">
            <option style="display:none;" value="" disabled selected>Como chegou até nós?</option>
            <option value="Anuncio" style="color:black">Anuncio</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, verifique no seu código essa linha: `<td colspan="2>` se está fechando com aspas duplas ficando dessa maneira: `<td colspan="2">`, se não estiver corrija. Sei que não tem a ver com a pergunta mas pode te ajudar  com eventuais problemas, foi sugerida essa edição na pergunta porém pode ser que seu código esteja assim, sem fechar as aspas duplas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fonte que você deseja adicionar é a Open Sans, o código que você está definindo é para adicionar a font Arial.

Ou seja, você deve utilizar um css assim:

```
select {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

## Editado:

Acredito que você esteja visualizando a font de placeholder, que por padrão não é afetada pelo código acima. Tente isso:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

### Editado 2

Tente fazer a definição em linha então, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <select name="lead_source" style="color:gray; width:100%; height:50px;" required="required">
            <option style="font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; display:none;" value="" disabled selected>Como chegou até nós?</option>
            <option style="font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:black" value="Anuncio">Anuncio</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Caso ainda não dê certo, uma última tentativa, mas não recomendada, seria de usar um `!important` no css do próprio select. Ou então, existe alguma outra propriedade de font sobrescrevendo a do select.

Comment: Adicionei e não funcinou, tentei adicionar font-size para aumentar a letra, e também não funciona.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima editei minha resposta, tente agora

Comment: Negativo Celsom, realmente estou usando placeholder porem somente nos input, nos Select não.

Comment: Adicionei o codigo do select a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima editado a resposta.

Comment: Trindade, mesmo com essa segunda opção continua sem funcionar.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima então você deve ter alguma propriedade de font sendo definida em outro local que esteja sobrescrevendo ela. Ou então, incompatibilidade de navegador. Em qual você está testando?

Comment: Ou então faça o seguinte, no chrome, inspecione o elemento e veja no console quais são as propriedades de font-family que estão atribuídas a ele e veja se existe alguma sobrepondo ela.

Comment: FF, Chrome, IE pelo Mobile

Comment: Usando o important consegui alterar.

Comment: Mas tome cuidado com o uso do `!important` pois você pode perder o controler de hierarquia do `css`

Answer (score 1):

### CSS

```
select{
   font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

Agora usando Herança de um Elemento Pai.

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select>
      <option> Teste de Fonte em Select </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.form-group{
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   font-size: 20px;
}

select{
   font-family: inherit;
   font-size: inherit;
}
```

O `inherit` herda do elemento Pai - no caso a `div.form-group` - as propriedades.
Mas como dito, não são todos os navegadores que entendem isso.

Comment: Adicionei e não funcinou, tentei adicionar font-size para aumentar a letra, e também não funciona.

Comment: Que navegador você está usando ? Veja se no FF e IE está funcionando caso esteja usando o Chrome ou Safari.

Comment: Estou testando em Mobile, FF e Chrome.

Comment: E funciona a fonte em algum deles ? Andei pesquisando aqui e é complicado fazer isso. Parece que só com plugin jQuery. Via `CSS` se faz por herança, mas nem todos os navegadores funcionam. Vou mostrar um exemplo de herança.